# Calling delegate method from Swift's Extension class

Tags: swift, objective-c-category, swift-extensions

All
I am implementing a UIAlertView extension for callback implementation like UIAlertView+Block in Objective C but the delegate method is not calling from this class any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your relevant code here.

Answer (score 0):

The callback from the alert view runs in a background thread and the code receiving it is probably running in the main thread, as per apple documentation:

From the Apple [iOS Documentation on Notification Centers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html):

> In a multithreaded application, notifications are always delivered in
>   the thread in which the notification was posted, which may not be the
>   same thread in which an observer registered itself.

You need to call the notification back in the main thread otherwise strange things can happen

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    //Call your notification from here
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(mySpecialNotificationKey, object: self)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, IcaroNZ, But my delegate method is not calling as a said.

Comment: @GopalDevra can you post your code so we help you review it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated answer after solving the issue.

```
typealias SelectBlock = (buttonIndex : Int) -> Void
typealias CancelBlock = () -> Void
private var blockSelect : SelectBlock?
private var blockCancel : CancelBlock?
extension UIAlertView {

    //Initilization
    func initWithTitle(
        title : String ,
        message : String,
        onSelect : SelectBlock?,
        onCancel : CancelBlock?,
        otherButtonTitles : [String]){

            //Initialize
            self.title = title
            self.delegate = self
            self.message = message

            //Block
            if let onSelectObj = onSelect? {
                blockSelect = onSelectObj
            }
            if let onCancelObj = onCancel? {
                blockCancel = onCancelObj
            }

            //Other buttons
            for buttons in otherButtonTitles {
                self.addButtonWithTitle(buttons)
            }

            //Cancel index
           // println("buttons \(self.numberOfButtons)")
            self.cancelButtonIndex = 0
            self.show()
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println("Index \(buttonIndex)")
        if buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex {
            blockCancel!()

           // println("Cancel")
        }else{
            blockSelect!(buttonIndex: buttonIndex)
            // println("Retry")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class is already a UIAlertView and you are creating another UIAlertView, you should change all the alertView for self. That should solve your problem

Comment: @GopalDevra: This is not an *answer* to your question. Please add *edit* your question and add the code to it.